# Mustache - Extract from Array

Tags: java, arrays, json, mustache

I am trying to get the specifiy variable "x-package" out of the mustache variables. The generated JSON Variable Tree looks like this:

```
"tags" : [ {
    "name" : "Dummy Name",
    "x-package" : "Dummy Package"
  } ]
```

What I need is the Value of x-package.

My current try is:

```
{{#tags}}
  {{x-package}}
{{/tags}}
```

But all it gives me, is a empty value.
(https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
{{#tags}}{{#.}}{{x-package}}{{/.}}{{/tags}}
```

`{{#.}}`..`{{/.}}` iterates over the array.